# Construction of a new distribution satisfying a certain threshold condition

Tags: distributions

I need to allocate a fixed amount $p^\star > 0$ among $N$ samples using a discrete distribution $P_i \in [0,1]$ satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^N P_i = 1$. In other words, each sample should receive the amount $P_i p^\star$.

The challenge is that there is an upper threshold distribution $\overline{P}_i$ for each sample, ensuring that no sample receives more than $\overline{P}_i p^\star$. Here, again we have $\sum_{i=1}^N \overline{P}_i = 1$.

Is there a way to construct a new distribution $Q_i$ for $i = 1, \dots, N$ that respects both the original distribution and the upper threshold condition?

Comment: It could be helpful if you provide a concrete example.

Comment: As a special case we could consider just $\overline{P}_i = 1/N$ which would result in the task to construct a modification $Q_i$ of $P_i$ so that $Q_i \leq 1/N$ for all $i = 1, \dots, N$ and $\sum_{i=1}^N Q_i =1$.

Comment: Numerically one could just "cut off" the amounts for samples that are above the threshold $\overline{P}_i$ and redistribute it to the remaining samples and then iterate this process. However, to me this appears to be a fairly unsatisfying approach.

Comment: Please consider adding all the relevant information directly to your post. Comments may get deleted or overlooked.